# Arduino servo not responding to button press

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm pretty sure there is a stupid error here but I'm afraid I can't for the life of me work it out!

Simple test program that gets the error:

```
#include <Servo.h> 

Servo myservo;

int testPIN = 13;
int inputPIN = 5;

void setup() 
{ 
  myservo.attach(8);
  pinMode(testPIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(inputPIN, INPUT);
} 

void loop() 
{ 
  if (digitalRead(inputPIN) == HIGH) 
  {
    digitalWrite(testPIN, HIGH);
    myservo.write(90);
  }
  else
  {    
    digitalWrite(testPIN, LOW);
    myservo.write(0);
  }
}
```

The arduino sweep example (http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Sweep) works, so I'm fairly confident the electronics works.

The testPIN also goes on and off as expected so the if statement is working as expected.

Any ideas/suggestions welcome!

EDIT - Sorry the error is that the servo doesn't move at all

EDIT 2 - Something a bit odd is going on here. If I copy/paste the sweep loop into the if clause, the servo reacts as expected (ie input = high makes the servo run a sweep loop, which it doesn't break out of until it reaches the end of, as expected). My immediate thought was delays were needed, but they seem to make no difference no matter how long they are or where they are added in the if/else clauses.

Comment: Sorry! See above. Thanks

Comment: On site you've mentioned the servo is on pin 9, in your code it's attached to pin 8... Just a wild guess.

Comment: Thanks but no luck I'm afraid, definitely on pin 8.

Comment: Something a bit odd is going on here. If I copy/paste the sweep loop into the if clause, the servo reacts as expected (ie input = high makes the servo run a sweep loop, which it doesn't break out of until it reaches the end of, as expected). My immediate thought was delays were needed, but they seem to make no difference no matter how long they are or where they are added in the if/else clauses.

Comment: You are not giving any delay after myservo.write().I think it will take some time for servo to respond. Also how you are managing the button pressed events? Probably you will need to add some debounce in button press. Also you need to maintain a small statemachine to sync you button press events and servo.

Comment: I've just being messing with delays to try to get a fix. Tried them after myservo.write() but no luck.

It's a simple microswitch, and it works well enough to trigger the sweep (see EDIT 2).

Comment: try playing with position and increment it gradually from zero to see if it works.

Comment: Nice idea, definitely something to do with this:

If I increase the increment at all it starts to react unpredictably (twitching etc), and if the delay is less than 10 same problem. The servo must not be able to react to big changes quickly.

Any ideas how to get round this? It seems clunky to write a for loop everytime I want to move the servo, especially as it will need checks for which way it is going.

Comment: Sorry I don't have any experience of servo and arduino. All I can suggest is to write a wrapper function over myservo.write which contains loop and delay along with increment step. Then probably you can try tuning increment step and delay for proper response. But I feel that should some better way than this.

Comment: What is connected to the input pin? If you don't have a pull-up or pull-down resistor you should set the input mode to INPUT_PULLUP.  Otherwise the input signal will be unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which arduino board you have, but on the arduino uno, i'm pretty sure that the pin 8 is not a **PWM** output. And you can not run a servo on a non-PWM output.

See this image of the Uno board, and notice that there is no tilde (the indication that a port supports PWM) on pin 8:

[image: Arduino Mega2560 board]

Comment: Thanks, but the servo works fine with the 'sweep' program, and just to make sure I just tried it on pin 7 and changed the code, no luck.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean - I'm using the Arduino Mega2560, no tildas on any of the pins.

Comment: @Bastyen You're welcome, but it seems it become moot since the 2560 doesn't show. [The pin mapping page](http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/PinMapping2560) shows that at least pins 6 through 13 support PWM.

Comment: yep right, on a Mega, the problem is not about the pin 8 (which is actually a PWM pin) unless the library servo.h doesn't support pin 8, but i don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using SoftwareServo.h instead? This example looks like what you are trying to accomplish: http://playground.arduino.cc/ComponentLib/servo

Answer (score 0):

The sweep program that you're linking to is using pin 9, which is a PWM on an uno.  Your code is using pin 8, which is NOT a PWM output.  Switch your servo over to pin 9 and change the attach in your code to pin 9 and, assuming that this is your only issue, your code should work.

Comment: What do you mean you can't control a servo on pin 8?!

Comment: It's an issue with certain arduino boards, as discussed above.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, I've just written a function that moves the servo slowly. Not an elegant solution but servo response time isn't issue so it does the trick.

Thanks for all the help and suggestions, and to @praks411 for the wrapper function work around.